# Cannot use @TaskAction annotation on method KaptWithoutKotlincTask.compile()

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have a problem with my project. When i want to run my project i got this error. I want to try this on Android 14 Beta.

A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Could not create task ':app:kaptMockDebugKotlin'.
> Cannot use @TaskAction annotation on method KaptWithoutKotlincTask.compile() because interface org.gradle.api.tasks.incremental.IncrementalTaskInputs is not a valid parameter to an action method.

My Settings:

Android Gradle Pulgin Version: 8.0.2
Gradle Version: 8.1

```
    tools_versions = [
            kotlin      : '1.9.0',
            agp         : '8.0.2',
            minSdk      : 21,
            compileSdk  : 34,
            targetSdk   : 34,
            sonarScanner: "3.0",
            ndk         : "21.0.6113669"
    ]
```

I change the gradle update everthing but nothing works

Comment: I could use an answer for this too.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I had to update a library

```
classpath "com.diffplug.spotless:spotless-plugin-gradle:6.23.3"
```

I got more details about my error by running

```
./gradlew build --warning-mode all
```

Comment: This works for the following kotlin, gradle ,spotless versions:-
kotlin: 1.9.0
agp:  < 8.0.0 
compileSdk  : 34
 targetSdk   : 34
spotless: 6.23.3

Answer (score 0):

This error might indicates an incompatibility between the versions of one the dependencies you have added to your `build.gradle` and the following Android project dependencies:

- Gradle Plugin
- Gradle Android Plugin
- Kotlin version

It looks like a third party dependency is using the Kapt compiler plugin, by using the `kapt` keyword before the library in your `dependencies` section, i.e.:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version" 
    ...
}
```

Can you update the question showing the other dependencies in your `build.gradle`?

Note also that KAPT is now in [maintenance mode](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/kapt.html) and so it is worth trying to find a version of the library that supports [KSP](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/ksp-overview.html) - the Kotlin Symbol Processing API

It may also be worth starting a brand new project from Android Studio using the New Project option in File/New: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/create-project.

See which versions of the Gradle Plugins and Kotlin are included by default for your version of Android Studio and SDK and try and use the same versions within your project, or just copy your existing source into this new project.